# i was trying to set my event dynamic but its not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

How to get events in events array what shroud I do if give fix index to     js_array its working but when I try to get through for loop its not working. when I push var in array and its print inside array its also not working.

How to set my events dynamic and set in this array what i do for this

Here's the example of what i'm doing.

```
<script>
var js_array = new Array();
$(document).ready(function() {
var js_array =<?php echo json_encode($date);?>;
var js_array1 =<?php echo json_encode($time);?>;
var js_arr = js_array.length;

for (var i = 0; i < js_arr; i++) {
var evn ="{ title: All Day Event, start: "+js_array[i]+" },";
var array3 = new Array;
array3.push(evn);
var test = array3.toString();
console.log(test);
//alert(test);
}


$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
defaultDate: '2016-09-01',
editable: true,
eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
events: [
//for (var i = 0; i < js_arr; i++) {
{
title: 'Appoinment',
start: js_array[0]
},
//}
{
title: 'Long Event',
start: js_array[1]
},
{
id: 999,
title: 'Repeating Event',
start: '2016-09-1216:00:00'
},
{

title: 'Repeating Event',
start: '2016-09-1216:00:00'
},
{
id: 999,
title: 'Repeating Event',
start: '2016-09-12T16:00:00'
},
{
title: 'Conference',
start: '2016-09-12',
end: '2016-09-13'
},
{
title: 'Conference',
start: '2016-09-12',
end: '2016-09-13'
},
{
title: 'Meeting',
start: '2016-09-12T10:30:00',
end: '2016-09-12T12:30:00'
},
{
title: 'Click for any link',
url: 'http://google.com/',
start: '2016-09-28'
}
]
//events: [test]
});

});

</script>
```

Comment: "not working"...that's quite a vague description. Explain in detail (with examples if necessary) what you _expect_ to happen, and what _actually_ happens.

Comment: i want this type  of output it's perfect output and  when i put fix index  0 and 1 calendar display but when i use for loop  inside events []  calendar not display. when  i put array3 inside events[] calendar also  not display

Comment: please edit the question, don't put large bits of code in the comments, it's very difficult to read!

Comment: This code is working and calendar display but when i start for loop and remove 0 and 1 index and also static date then calendar not display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the FullCalendar, the "events" property must be either an array, a function, or a URL which returns a JSON object.

Your original code (for anyone else reading, see edit history) was attempting to run a for loop inside an array declaration. That's completely invalid JS. I should think you were getting a console error in your browser, although you didn't mention one.

You need to enclose this loop in a function and then return the event array from the function (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/) :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: '2016-09-01',
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
      var event_arr = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < js_array.length; i++) {
         event_arr.push({ 
           title: 'Appointment', 
           start: js_array[i]
           //add any other properties here as required, e.g. end date/time
         });
      }
      callback(event_arr);
    }
});
```

P.S. That's the simplest solution to this specific problem, but personally if you have control over what is returned by PHP from the server, I would make that return a set of events in the correct format required by fullCalendar, rather than messing about with it on the client-side like this. It would be a lot easier to manage it that way (in my opinion). For instance, then you could just write something like:

```
events: <?php echo json_encode($calendarEvents);?>
```

on the client-side. And you would have changed the PHP to insert the correct info into the objects within the `$calendarEvents` array already.

Comment: it's perfect solution..thanks...but what should i do for time same as  date..? start: js_array[i]+'T'+js_array1[i], it's a right way or not...?

Comment: yeah given your current code that would be the way to solve it, assuming the format of the data is correct. BTW if the answer has helped you please don't forget to accept it and/or upvote - thanks :-)

Comment: i was try but it's not working and  calendar not display then i will try js_array[i]+'T12:30:00' but still it's not working calendar disappear   i don't knw what actually happen.how to fix this issue

Comment: does it give any error in the browser console (F12)?

Comment: just give me warning .......Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date.

Comment: probably it doesn't understand the format. You should check your date/time format combination corresponds with those accepted by moment (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)